# Accessing a "parent" functions' variable

Tags: javascript

In javascript is there any way to have mod() modify a? what i want to do:

```
function whatever(){
  var a=0;
  mod(a);
  var amodded=a;
}
function mod(obj){
  obj++
  a=obj;
}
```

At the end of whatever() i want 'amodded' to be =1. Is there any way to do that without declaring 'a' outside of any and all functions?

Answer (score 0):

1.　Make `mod` such that it changes [properties of] `a` directly:

```
function whatever (){
    var a = {value: 0};
    mod(a);
    var amodded = a.value;
}

function mod(obj){
    obj.value++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2jL0we41/

2.　Make `mod` such that it returns the new value:

```
function whatever (){
    var a       = 0,
        amodded = mod(a);
}

function mod(obj){
    return ++obj;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jv9ya841/